# Add association to SpringSecurity User class

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I'm trying to add a reference from the default Spring Security user domain class to another class which should hold additional user info.

```
class User {
    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Profile profile
      ...
```

...and...

```
class Profile {
    static constraints = {
    }

    static belongsTo = [user : User]

    String firstName
    String lastName     
}
```

From what I read this should be the way it works, but I get the following error :

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: null
Message: null
   Line | Method
->>  32 | create                           in com.app.UserRole
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    15 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
|   301 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|   294 | executeForEnvironment            in     ''
|   270 | executeForCurrentEnvironment . . in     ''
|   303 | innerRun                         in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask                          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   662 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us your error producing code from BoorStrap.groovy ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see your `BootStrap` to be sure, but I suspect it's because you're doing something like

```
def user = new User(....).save()
def role = new Role(....).save()
UserRole.create(user, role)
```

and your new `User` is failing validation (which causes `save` to return `null`).

If you use `save(failOnError:true)` you should get a different exception with a better indication of what the real problem is.  Check that you have the right `constraints` in your `User` class, in particular note that GORM properties are by default non-nullable so if you want to be able to save a `User` that doesn't have a `Profile` you will need to add a constraint of `profile(nullable:true)`.

Comment: Setting the nullable: true constraint did it. Thank you very much!